# google custom search positioning in firefox

Tags: html, css

im having an issue with adding in a custom google search engine into this website i am working on. 
The positioning of the search bar was causing some problems for me originally in chrome and IE. It was supposed to be in the center div, and it would infact show up in the center but it would show only after every other div before it was loaded. so it it gave me this huge white space instead of just starting in the center div.
i managed it get it working in chrome and IE, but it still doesn't work on firefox.

```
#searchbar{
width:620px;
margin: 22px 160px;
position:relative;
clear:both; 
max-height:500px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

[Chrome Picture](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-s-munyFEthZEgzbTlKaFNncGM/edit?usp=sharing)

[FireFox Picture](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-s-munyFEthWXY0dzY4Y1NiZjQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Also Absolute positioning doesn't work out very well because if you stretch the screen it could go over the wrap div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you making use of a CSS reset tool like: [erik meyer's css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)?

these resets typically help get more consistency between the way different browsers render the css effects onto the markup.  i would start there, if it doesnt directly fix the position, it will set appearance so both browsers are rendering the search bar similarly.  then you can accurately decide how to adjust it, without having to play tug of war between the different browsers

Comment: i tried that, and it did infact make this code work in each browser. thanks :)